# Is it possible to store the edited lines [the ones highlighted in green in the side] in SourceInsight/Source Insight?

Tags: ide, source-insight

Whether is it possible to store the highlight that source insight shows for edited lines? I wish the highlight to be stored till I discard it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no way Source Insight can support this. Checked the SI support team and got this confirmation.